# make command error: undefined reference to `pthread_create

Tags: linux, makefile, pthreads

I was trying to run the codes from [sourceforge.net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rsvp-agent/), but when I was trying to run the "make" command in linux, I got the following error message:

```
make  all-recursive

make[1]: Entering directory `/home/lliu/MyDoc/rsvp-agent/trunk/agent_rsvp'
Making all in src

make[2]: Entering directory `/home/lliu/MyDoc/rsvp-agent/trunk/agent_rsvp/src'
/bin/sh ../libtool --mode=link --tag=CXX g++  -g -O2   -o agent_rsvp   agent_rsvp.o configuration.o floatformat.o generic_interface.o ip_mask.o ip_route.o mgmt_interface.o mgmt_packet.o mpls_ioctl.o rsvp_configuration.o rsvp_connection.o rsvp_dispatcher.o rsvp_error.o rsvp_packet.o rsvp_socket.o semaphore.o tools.o verbose.o

g++ -g -O2 -o agent_rsvp agent_rsvp.o configuration.o floatformat.o generic_interface.o ip_mask.o ip_route.o mgmt_interface.o mgmt_packet.o mpls_ioctl.o rsvp_configuration.o rsvp_connection.o rsvp_dispatcher.o rsvp_error.o rsvp_packet.o rsvp_socket.o semaphore.o tools.o verbose.o
mgmt_interface.o: In function `mgmt_interface::init()':
/home/lliu/MyDoc/rsvp-agent/trunk/agent_rsvp/src/mgmt_interface.cpp:108: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
/home/lliu/MyDoc/rsvp-agent/trunk/agent_rsvp/src/mgmt_interface.cpp:109: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
rsvp_connection.o: In function `rsvp_connection::create_refresh_thread()':
/home/lliu/MyDoc/rsvp-agent/trunk/agent_rsvp/src/rsvp_connection.cpp:136: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
rsvp_dispatcher.o: In function `rsvp_dispatcher::init(unsigned int)':
/home/lliu/MyDoc/rsvp-agent/trunk/agent_rsvp/src/rsvp_dispatcher.cpp:72: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [agent_rsvp] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/lliu/MyDoc/rsvp-agent/trunk/agent_rsvp/src'

make[1 ]: * ** [all-recursive] Error 1

make[1 ]: Leaving directory `/home/lliu/MyDoc/rsvp-agent/trunk/agent_rsvp'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: You need to add `-pthread` to the compile and link lines, if you want to use the pthread library.

Comment: would you mind showing me how to do that? You mean in which file should I add that line, in the "make" file or the "mgmt_interface.cpp" file?

Comment: In the makefile.  I can't give you specifics since I don't know what your makefile looks like, plus it looks like you are using autoconf and libtool.  You could try this: when you invoke make, run it as: `make CXXFLAGS='-g -O2 -pthread'`  You'll have to do that every time you run make.  I assume this tool uses autoconf (configure); you could do it at configure time too instead of at `make` time.